# Starting a .app file from java

Tags: java, macos, .app

I need run a system call to run a .app file from java.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String cmd = "./file.app";
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = run.exec(cmd);
pr.waitFor();
```

Something like that?

Comment: Application bundles on the Mac are just specially laid out folders.  The path to the binary would actually be something like:

/Applications/App.app/Contents/MacOS/App

Comment: I'd set cmd to "open ./file.app"